# why While loop keep moves to below statement even though it becomes true?

Tags: python, while-loop

I have come up with the below line of code to solve: *Using while loop keep asking for user input till user come up with the number in range(1,11)*.

My question is when I put *123* as input, my while loop still works. Why? Shouldn't it quit since **user_input.isdigit() becomes True** for *123* as input?

```py
def userinput():
    
    user_input = 'wrong'   

    while user_input.isdigit() == False:
        
        while user_input not in range(1,11):
            
            user_input = input('What no. are you proposing in range(1,10)?  :')

            if user_input.isdigit() == False or int(user_input) not in range(1,11):

                print(f'Please try again\n')

            else:
                print('You have guessed correctly!')
                break

    return int(user_input)
```

Comment: You have two conditions. `123` matches `int(user_input) not in range(1,11)` so you don't go to the else part and so the loop does not break.

Comment: To refactor your code you could replace both `while` loops with just one `while True:` loop. This would be something like "Run forever until I break from it".

Comment: @Matthias Does it mean that for *123* as input, instead of moving to outer while loop directly.i first looped through inner while loop and if it gets true then i go for cross-checking through outer while loop?

Comment: @matthias and tal *while True* is also offering an alternative approach. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Your inner loop condition is not met so your outer loop condition is not checked.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
def userinput():
    
    user_input = 'wrong'   

    while True:
            
        user_input = input('What no. are you proposing in range(1,10)?  :')
        if user_input.isdigit() == False or int(user_input) not in range(1,11):
            print(f'Please try again\n')
        else:
            print('You have guessed correctly!')
            break

    return int(user_input)
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider this simpler alternative.

```
def userinput():
    user_input = 0
    while user_input not in range(1, 11):
        user_input = input('What no. are you proposing in range(1,10)?  :')
        if user_input.isdigit() and int(user_input) in range(1, 11):
            print('You have guessed correctly!')
            break
        else:
            print(f'Please try again\n')
    return int(user_input)
```

Comment: it will fail if input are non- numerical characters!!

Comment: I modified to prevent issues with non-numerical characters.